# function to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number

Tags: javascript

i need to create a fibonacci function, i figured out the code for positive values

```
const fib = n => {
  let prev = 0, next = 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    next = prev + next;
    prev = next - prev;
  }
  return prev;
}
```

maybe someone will tell you how to write code when n is a negative number

Comment: I think there's no difference. The starting of fibanocci is just by definition 0 and 1 so in my opinion cause it is an inifinit line of numbers you can choose whatever you want. prev = -36 and next = -24 but I'm not a math person.

Comment: With Math.abs() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const fib = n => {
  const isPositive = n >= 0
  let prev = 0, next = 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.abs(n); i++){
    next = prev + next;
    prev = next - prev;
  }
  return isPositive ? prev : prev * -1;
}
```